# Comparar un datarow con un string

Tags: c#, array, string

Buenos días tengo el siguiente código para la generación de un archivo excel en c#

```
int i = 5;
int f = 0;   
foreach (DataRow Row in DS.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    f = f + 1;
    // Asignar los valores de los registros a las celdas
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "A"] = f;
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "B"] = Row.ItemArray[0];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "C"] = Row.ItemArray[1];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "D"] = Row.ItemArray[2];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "E"] = Row.ItemArray[3];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "F"] = Row.ItemArray[4];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "G"] = Row.ItemArray[5];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "H"] = Row.ItemArray[6];
    HojaExcel.Cells[i, "I"] = Row.ItemArray[7];
    if (Row.ItemArray[7] == "REALIZADO")
    {
         HojaExcel.Cells[i, "G"] = "0";
    }
    // Avanzamos una fila
    i++;
}
```

Estoy tratando de hacer una comprobación en base a la ultima columna que no sabría si es la manera correcta o no de validarlo , pero al final quiero que si los datos contenidos en la columna **I** tengo tipeado **Realizado** en la columna **G** se digite el numero 0.

De antemano agradezco su colaboración.

Saludos Cordiales.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas hacer es añadir la conversión `ToString` del elemento:

```
if (Row.ItemArray[7].ToString() == "REALIZADO")...
```

aunque dicho sea de paso, también podrías cambiar la evaluación así:

```
if (Row.ItemArray[7].ToString().Equals("REALIZADO"))...
```